# Change button alignment of buttonA when buttonB is GONE

Tags: android, button, alignment, android-relativelayout, visibility

I have placed two buttons `prev` and `next` in a `RelativeLayout`. When I reach the last page of my app, I am disabling the `next` button using :

```
next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The alignment of `prev` button is disrupted. I want it to be aligned to the centre of the `RelativeLayout`, as if there was only one button.

Here is my code :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radgroup"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/previous"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="23dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/prev"
        android:onClick="viewPreviousQuestion"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/previous"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="23dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/prev"
        android:id="@+id/nxt"
        android:onClick="viewNextQuestion"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the `onClick` event is

```
public void viewNextQuestion(View view) {
    if(currqstn==lastqstn){
        next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your layout code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a Relative Layout here,Use a Linear Layout Instead.
Since in a Relative layout Views are positioned with respect to one another, when you remove one view,it might disrupt other views that were positioned with respect to the deleted view.

EDIT

Use can use the following attributes for your views:  weightSum, weight and padding.

Answer (score 2):

Use **Linear Layout** to cover both the buttons Inside YOur main Relative Layout and and set

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
```

to your **prev** button.

Comment: I have, but it doesn't show publicly because my rep is below 15

Answer (score 1):

When you using `View.Gone` its remove view place and **other views are disturb**

**AND**

when you using `View.Invisible` its always there just **view is hidden** and **others views are not disturb**.

use this...........

```
next.setVisibility(View.Invisible);
```

enjoy coding .....

Comment: But, if I set it to INVISIBLE, the `prev` button remains in its place. I don't want that. It should appear at the centre.